# Execute Java Timer at every 2 hours

Tags: java, timer, scheduling

I have a timer routine I want to execute every two hours. But my logic below seem to execute too early than expected. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
         (new Timer()).scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
          {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {

              try
              {                  
               //TODO: Perform routine.
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                try
                {
                  throw ex;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
              }
            }

          }, 0, (1000 * 60 * 120));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `try-catch` looks pretty bad...

Comment: What do you mean by 'too early' ?

Comment: Though this won't change your results, you should use TimeUnit.  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)

Comment: @Martijn Try-catch should pass the exception to main to be caught.

Comment: @John i think the value passed to initial delay was the reason why it did execute quickly. My bad.

Comment: Yea I knew what I commented wouldn't change anything you would see, just figure I note that as a better practice.

Comment: @Bitmap: If you want to do that, remove the inner try-catch, and rethrow it as this: `new RuntimeException("Error in scheduling", e);`. Because, your current throw statement will be immediately catched by the inner try-catch.

Comment: @Martijn Sounds like a decent plan. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29), your code should trigger the routine immediately (initial delay of zero), then after every 2 hours (period of 120 minutes).

> scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task,
>   long delay, long period)
>
> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-rate execution,
>   beginning after the specified delay.

If you want the first triggering after 2 hours then do

```
long interval = 1000 * 60 * 120;
scheduleAtFixedRate(task, interval, interval)
```

Comment: +1, for explaining what was wrong with his code, rather than providing an entirely different implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever possible, use the [`Executors`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) framework instead of a `Timer`.

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // do stuff
    }}, 0, 2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this approach, please? And how do you stop the task at a later time?

Comment: @DNA, see section [6.2.5 Delayed and periodic tasks](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0321349601/task-execution/120#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTAzMjEzNDk2MDEvMTIz)

Comment: @DNA One of the advantage that explain there is that Timer will have delayed in case of long tasks, but Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate will also suffer in delay in case of long task, so i didnt get the advantage. I am looking for fixRate ,but from the start of the task and not upon end of the task is there a solution for it ?